# PulseAudio unable to detect Bluetooth Headset

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I am able to successfully pair with my bluetooth headset (Motorola S305), and connect to Audio Sink. However, it does not show up in PulseAudio (in any way I ask it), and I can't switch the audio profile (HSP/HFP, A2DP, Off) away from Off.

Comment: There are issues with BT in 14.04 (e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1181106) can you see the device on using [**pavucontrol**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/)?

Comment: @Takkat Nope, never appears in pavucontrol.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command `gksudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` and see if that helps.

Comment: Did not add the device to PulseAudio and now I can't connect to Audio Sink ("Connection Failed: Stream setup failed" from blueman).

Comment: Yes, I occasionally get similar errors. Try restarting bluetooth (`sudo service bluetooth restart`?

Comment: Restarting bluetooth doesn't change anything.

Comment: That normally works for me, I don't know I'm afraid.